# Ruby chef os related

Tags: ruby, automation, chef-infra

I need to remove the tab space from  the array and compare the values with one array value with a string.

```
inspec> command("chage -l root").stdout.split("\n").flatten{|x| x.strip || x}
=> ["Last password change\t\t\t\t\t: Feb 27, 2017",
 "Password expires\t\t\t\t\t: May 28, 2017",
 "Password inactive\t\t\t\t\t: Apr 20, 2067",
 "Account expires\t\t\t\t\t\t: Nov 27, 2019",
 "Minimum number of days between password change\t\t: 0",
 "Maximum number of days between password change\t\t: 90",
 "Number of days of warning before password expires\t: 7"]
inspec>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What is the code you are having trouble with? What is the problem with your code? Do you get an error? If yes, what is the precise error you are getting? Does the actual result differ from the expected result? If yes, what is the result you are expecting, why are you expecting that result, what is the actual result and how do they differ? Does the observed behavior of the code differ from the intended behavior? If yes, what is the intended behavior and why, what is the behavior you are seeing, and how do they differ? What is the specification for the intended behavior?

Comment: my query i need to remove the "\t\t\t :" on the array indexes

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array#map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-map) and [String#gsub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-gsub).

So the code will be:

`command("chage -l root").stdout.split("\n").flatten{|x| x.strip || x}.map{|x| x.gsub(/\t/, '')}`